# Why Does 'grep' Change Text Format in Swaymsg Output?

Tags: json, regex, linux, text, grep

I'm using `swaymsg -t get_inputs | grep` to filter input device information, but I've noticed that `grep` is altering the text format.

###### Using grep:

```bash
$ swaymsg -t get_inputs | grep -i touch
    "identifier": "2:7:SynPS\/2_Synaptics_TouchPad",
    "name": "SynPS\/2 Synaptics TouchPad",
    "type": "touchpad",
```

###### Without grep:

```bash
$ swaymsg -t get_inputs

Input device: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
  Type: Touchpad
  Identifier: 2:7:SynPS/2_Synaptics_TouchPad
  Product ID: 7
  Vendor ID: 2
  Libinput Send Events: enabled
```

Why does this unusual behavior occur, and is there a way to make 'grep' preserve the text exactly as it is?

Comment: Swaymsg knows the difference between a pipe and a file. But that's not really a programming problem. Voted to migrate to [su].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not `grep` that changes the output, it's `swaymsg`. It detects the output is not a terminal and switches to JSON output. Try specifying the `--pretty` option.

Answer (score 0):

`swaymsg` does both plain "text" and `json`.  It just defaults to plain text when `stdout` is a `tty`.

```
man swaymsg
```

You can force the plain text output with `-p`

You can force the `json` output with `-r`

The `json` output is useful when output to a file  `> your_file.json` or when using a tool such as `jq` to parse individual `json` components which in your case it would be super simple to grab `name`, `type` or `identifier` individually rather than having to `awk` an output ...